# Is it a bug to use msg_accrights to send &fd between processes?

Tags: c, nginx

Quoted from [here](http://ncache.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.2/src/os/unix/ngx_channel.c):

```
    msg.msg_accrights = (caddr_t) &ch->fd;
    msg.msg_accrightslen = sizeof(int);
    ...
    n = sendmsg(s, &msg, 0);
```

IMHO `&ch->fd` can't be shared between processes(the address of `fd` won't be available in another process),should transfer `ch->fd` directly,

am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending the address of the fd. You are sending an array (with 1 element in this case). Since only one fd is sent, the address of the filedescriptor itself is used, as there is really no difference between doing that and doing:

```
int fds[1];
fds[1] = ch->fd;
msg.msg_accrights = (caddr_t) fds;
msg.msg_accrightslen = sizeof fds;
```

sendmsg will send the value of that array, so the other end will receive the file descriptor value, not the address of the file descriptor.

Comment: Nice to know it sends the value,not address:)

Answer (score 0):

`msg_accrights` points to an array of file descriptors, so the code is correct when passing a single file descriptor.

The general form of this call is something like:

```
int fds[2];
fds[0] = an_fd;
fds[1] = another_fd;
msg.msg_accrights = (caddr_t) fds;
msg.msg_accrightslen = sizeof fds;
...
n = sendmsg(s, &msg, 0);
```

Comment: I'm very confused..does `sendmsg` send the address of fd(`&fd`) or fd finally?

Comment: For your purposes, it sends the address, which is expected to point to an array of `fd`s whose length is given by `msg_accrightslen`. This means that if you want to transfer multiple file descriptors, you don't need to make multiple `sendmsg()` calls, just one specifying an array. I'll annotate the answer.